# Find k closest numbers to the median

Tags: algorithms

The formal problem statement is: Given a set S of n distinct numbers and a positive integer k<=n, determine the k numbers in S closest to the median. 
**My thoughts:**
I have read about the median of median algorithm, which goes like group n elements in groups of 5 and finds the median of them and then recursively finds the median of the resulting array, which will have size n/5. This runs in O(n) time. So once we have the median, how to go about finding the k closest element to it, that seems to be another tricky thing.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** try to transform the $n$ elements in such a way that the $k$ closest to the median will be the smallest $k$ elements after the transformation.

**Hint 2:** now use a standard algorithm to find the $k$'th smallest value (also known as the $k$'th order statistic). You might have learned an algorithm that computes this as a variation of the quickselect algorithm

Comment: Changing to |a-median| will transform like that. But how will that yield k closest to the median. I am looking for an O(n) solution

Comment: okay, so once you have the kth smallest value, you can find all the numbers less than it in a single iteration